# Kraken ate Jebediah - any way to resurrect him?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I landed on [Minmus](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Minmus). Some parts exploded, but that's only to be expected, it's Kerbal Space Program after all. I got [Jebediah](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Jeb) EVA to take some samples, and [Hell Kraken](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Kraken#Hell_Kraken) ate him. Screen got blank, altitude meter got 666,666 and then random, and after restart Jeb is listed as lost.

Is there any way to resurrect him? Probably save edit? I want him alive, and if possible I want him where I lost him - next to the ship he was piloting (a lot of science to bring back home). I have my persistence file backed up and it appears to be complete (minus Jeb) state of my universe at the moment of failure, so by editing him in I would be able to play as if bug never happened.

Comment: I'm not versed in Kerbal, but for *any* game, unless you backed up your save or the game maintains a cache of several older auto-saves that haven't been overwritten yet, you aren't going to be able to return to an exact previous state. You may be able to bring back Jeb and even position him where you want him, and maybe your ship and science are still there, but returning to "when" he was is not likely because time will have passed and aspects of the universe changed within Kerbal's simulation.

Comment: @skovacs1 time hasn't passed - when Hell Kraken attacks, all simulation goes nuts and persistence file is no longer updated. Game must be restarted to play. So I have the exact moment saved (and backed up now), minus Jebediah, who is marked dead. Everything else is exactly as it was and no time has passed, at least not in backup. I have pre-landing quicksave, but landing is the step when things explode most often, so I would rather avoid repeating it.

Comment: I think you should try landing without anything exploding. Minmus is probably the most forgiving body to land on, it will be hard for you to land on other bodies if you can't manage to do it there.

Comment: @Baarn my rockets always explode a bit ;) truth is, I tried to land on a stage I was supposed to decouple before touchdown, but I made my landing too fuel efficient, and I tried to save stage too hard. Wouldn't try it on a body with higher gravity. Worry not, I play since 0.14 and know my ways around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never did that before, but I think you should be able to do it by manually editing the saves files. More precisely the `persistent.sfs` file.

There is a `ROSTER` category located somewhere down the file where you can find all your crew members. (Lookup their name!)

You can revive them by setting their state back to 0.

(Seems to be confirmed by http://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/threads/41891-How-to-revive-the-%28bob-bill-and-jebediah%29)

You can as well add Jebediah to the command pod. Lookup the ship's name into the file and locate the `crew = x` value. Change this to the number of crew member you want to add. Jebediah should be 0.

Comment: OK, he's alive, but I also had to edit him manually into the ship. Then, I went EVA again. Almost perfect, close enough. Will accept if you will add this note to an answer ;)

Comment: Done. You could have edited my answer, it's fine.

Comment: I somehow have a strong feelings against editing answers by others, if it changes their meaning - even if only by adding to it.